# Filter Results from Cursor in CursorAdapter Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am using LoaderCallbacks to get all data from my tabel.
And After getting the cursor like this and setting it in cursoradapter.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderNumber, Bundle bundle) {

        String[] projection = {
                MyDeals.Columns._ID,
                 MyDeals.Columns.LATITUDE,
                MyDeals.Columns.LONGITUDE,
                MyDeals.Columns.PHONENUMBER
                };

        return new CursorLoader(mActivity, MyDeals.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);  

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {

    dealsBaseAdapter = new DealsBaseAdapter(mActivity, cursor, CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);
    mDealListView.setAdapter(dealsBaseAdapter);
}
```

Now in my cursoradapter i want to filter some data based on distance. for each item i fetch from db.
Suppose if get three data  as

```
                              Data A , lat_A = 5.5, long_A=5.2
                             Data B , lat_B = 5.5, long_B=5.2
                             Data C , lat_C = 5.5, long_C=5.2

Now based on by present location i calculate the distance between my location and Data A location. if location is <=(someValue) then show deal in list else not.
```

The same for all deals i get from cursor.

At which place i can filter my deal like this  :)

Answer (score 0):

see [CursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FilterQueryProvider.html)